# How can I match tokens while listening to an Antlr4 grammar?

Tags: c#, compiler-construction, antlr, antlr4, abstract-syntax-tree

I've been working on a language implementation based on a very large grammar that someone else wrote. I'm using Antlr 4.12 and targeting C#. Everything is going quite well and I make lots of progress. I'm using listeners because I think it's the easist way to translate the sytnax tree into actions for my language.

One thing that bothers me is a certain construct that seems more difficult to parse in C# than it could be. For example, I might be parsing expressions, which involve literals and operators and functions -- all the usual stuff. For functions, there are several different types of functions, grouped together as a `function_call`.

```
    function_call
        : ranking_windowed_function                         #RANKING_WINDOWED_FUNC
        | aggregate_windowed_function                       #AGGREGATE_WINDOWED_FUNC
        | analytic_windowed_function                        #ANALYTIC_WINDOWED_FUNC
        | built_in_functions                                #BUILT_IN_FUNC
        | scalar_function_name '(' expression_list? ')'     #SCALAR_FUNCTION
        | freetext_function                                 #FREE_TEXT
        | partition_function                                #PARTITION_FUNC
        | hierarchyid_static_method                         #HIERARCHYID_METHOD
        ;
```

I might implement `EnterSomeExpression_Context()` and get the root of the expression in the syntax tree. As I traverse it, I'll end up finding a `function_callContext`. That context itself isn't particularly useful by itself because I need to know which of these types I'm working with.

How can I discover that in C#?  The only way I have right now is to compare the runtime types using `is`:

```
    if (obj is RANKING_WINDOWEDFUNCTContext) 
    {
       // handle a ranking windowing function ...
    }
    else if (obj is BUILT_IN_FUNCContext)
    {
       // handle a built-in ...
    }
    else if (obj is FREE_TEXTContext)
    {
       // handle a free-text query ...
    }
    // and so on ...
```

which works for small bunches of choices, but after a few then I long for a way to have a lookup table. And I always want a more direct comparison (like with an integer or an enum) instead of checking types and casting around.

How should this code be written? Or am I actually doing it the right way?

If it helps, the grammar is for T-SQL, here: https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4/tree/master/sql/tsql And all of my code is in my JankSQL project: https://github.com/mikeblas/JankSQL

EDIT: Why is this question getting a negative score? Did I miss some information? Does something need to be clarified?

Comment: Wouldn't creating a delegate dictionary Dictionary<Type,Func<>> help?

Comment: I might have an idea for you, but your question and the other comments are so vague, I'm not sure what you are really after. What information do really want to get from the parse tree? A symbol table generated from the parse tree would help to identify structure and data types.

Comment: Perhaps a visitor might be more suitable in your case? Given that each visitor method returns an actual object instead of the `void` listener methods.

Comment: I think what you are asking about is an alternative to a nested if-then-else's in the `function_call` visitor. If so, you have several options. (a) You can synthesize an attribute, and use that in a switch statement in your `function_call` visitor. (b) Calculate a hash value from the C# type and use that in a switch statement in your `function_call` visitor. (c) Use the C# type in a switch statement in `function_call` visitor. (d) Move the vistor code to a lower-level parse tree node visitor.

Comment: @kaby76  The conditionals aren't nested, they're linear.

Answer (score 0):

The "comments" are using the [alternative label syntax](https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/blob/master/doc/parser-rules.md#alternative-labels).  That link details how this works, but the short of it is that you should have listeners for `enterRANKING_WINDOWED_FUNC` `exitRANKING_WINDOWED_FUNC`, etc. for each alternative in your grammar rule.  Each method will receive an alternative-specific context that will be much easier to work with.

(NOTE: Not sure why they went with all uppercase, it makes for strange names...)

Comment: Indeed, there are `EnterSomething` and `ExitSomething` functions available. But the problem is that there's little context in these functions: I'm inside the expression deep, and not anywhere near the related operators. And it's possible that a complicated command has a few different kinds of expressions, and ...

With so little context, the listeners must all manage a tremendous amount of state, essentially recreating their own model of the AST just to fit together the statement. I don't think these callbacks address my question.

Answer (score 0):

Based upon this part of your question:

" I always want a more direct comparison (like with an integer or an enum) instead of checking types and casting around."

You might leverage [getAltNumber](https://www.antlr.org/api/Java/org/antlr/v4/runtime/RuleContext.html#getAltNumber()).  This will require you to "Create a subclass of ParserRuleContext with backing field and set option contextSuperClass. to set it.".  But it would give you a number you could use to identify which alternative of the `function_call` you have (as an integer).